# Комбинаторика в DataFrame с исключением Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, комбинаторика

Подскажите, как просуммировать столбцы названии которых уникально?

Есть `df1` и `df2`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'C': [9, 10, 11, 12], 'D': [13, 14, 15, 16], 'E': [17, 18, 19, 20],  'F': [21, 22, 23, 24], 'G': [25, 26, 27, 28], 'H': [29, 30, 31, 32], 'L': [33, 34, 35, 36], 'K': [37, 38, 39, 40], 'M': [41, 42, 43, 44], 'P': [45, 46, 47, 48]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [254, 223, 335,222], 'B': [545, 667, 743, 856], 'D': [986, 104, 113, 124], 'E': [137, 149, 165, 176]})
```

на этом шаге в `df1` провожу суммирование столбцов и получаю `df_summ` все хорошо.

```
my_list=[(pd.Series(df1.loc[:,list(i)].sum(axis=1), name='_'.join(df1.loc[:,list(i)].columns))) for i in list(itertools.combinations(df1.columns,2))] 
df_summ=pd.concat(my_list,axis=1)
print(df_summ)

   A_B  A_C  A_D  A_E  A_F  A_G  A_H  ...  H_P  L_K  L_M  L_P  K_M  K_P  M_P
0    6   10   14   18   22   26   30  ...   74   70   74   78   78   82   86
1    8   12   16   20   24   28   32  ...   76   72   76   80   80   84   88
2   10   14   18   22   26   30   34  ...   78   74   78   82   82   86   90
3   12   16   20   24   28   32   36  ...   80   76   80   84   84   88   92

[4 rows x 66 columns]
```

Вот тут вопрос, как просуммировать `df_summ` и `df2`, так что бы суммировались столбцы уникальные. Вроде как эту функцию `itertools.product` можно применить.

Примерно должно получиться так:

```
    A_B+D  A_C+D  A_D+B  A_E+B  A_F+B  A_G+B  A_H+B  
0    992    996    559    563    567    571    575   
1    112    116    683    687    691    695    699   
2    123    127    761    765    769    773    777   
3    136    140    876    880    884    888    892
```

Comment: Что значит у вас "уникальные столбцы"?

Comment: не повторяющийся буквы, получается так: первый столбец из `df_summ` эта  A_B, так вот к нему можно тока приплюсовать столбец  D и E из  `df2`, получается появятся два столбца A_B+D и A_B+E и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то можно сделать так:

Исходные:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'C': [9, 10, 11, 12], 'D': [13, 14, 15, 16], 'E': [17, 18, 19, 20],  'F': [21, 22, 23, 24], 'G': [25, 26, 27, 28], 'H': [29, 30, 31, 32], 'L': [33, 34, 35, 36], 'K': [37, 38, 39, 40], 'M': [41, 42, 43, 44], 'P': [45, 46, 47, 48]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [254, 223, 335,222], 'B': [545, 667, 743, 856], 'D': [986, 104, 113, 124], 'E': [137, 149, 165, 176]})
```

Сразу получаем список столбцов, общий для обоих фреймов, проводим конкатенацию и делаем красивые имена столбцов:

```
df1_cols = list(itertools.combinations(df1.columns,2))
cols = [x+tuple(y) for x in df1_cols for y in df2.columns.to_list() if y not in x]
res = pd.concat([df1[c[0]].add(df1[c[1]].add(df2[c[2]])) for c in cols], axis=1, keys=cols)
res.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in res.columns.values]
```

получаем res:

```
   A_B_D  A_B_E  A_C_B  A_C_D  A_C_E  A_D_B  A_D_E  A_E_B  A_E_D  A_F_B  ...  \
0    992    143    555    996    147    559    151    563   1004    567  ...   
1    112    157    679    116    161    683    165    687    124    691  ...   
2    123    175    757    127    179    761    183    765    135    769  ...   
3    136    188    872    140    192    876    196    880    148    884  ...   

   K_M_D  K_M_E  K_P_A  K_P_B  K_P_D  K_P_E  M_P_A  M_P_B  M_P_D  M_P_E  
0   1064    215    336    627   1068    219    340    631   1072    223  
1    184    229    307    751    188    233    311    755    192    237  
2    195    247    421    829    199    251    425    833    203    255  
3    208    260    310    944    212    264    314    948    216    268
```

**UPDATE**

Если нужно получить промежуточный фрейм df_summ, то можно сделать так:

```
my_list=[(pd.Series(df1.loc[:,list(i)].sum(axis=1), name='_'.join(df1.loc[:,list(i)].columns))) for i in list(itertools.combinations(df1.columns,2))] 
df_summ=pd.concat(my_list,axis=1)
```

Соответственно, df_summ получится:

```
   A_B  A_C  A_D  A_E  A_F  A_G  A_H  A_L  A_K  A_M  ...  H_L  H_K  H_M  H_P  \
0    6   10   14   18   22   26   30   34   38   42  ...   62   66   70   74   
1    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40   44  ...   64   68   72   76   
2   10   14   18   22   26   30   34   38   42   46  ...   66   70   74   78   
3   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40   44   48  ...   68   72   76   80   

   L_K  L_M  L_P  K_M  K_P  M_P  
0   70   74   78   78   82   86  
1   72   76   80   80   84   88  
2   74   78   82   82   86   90  
3   76   80   84   84   88   92
```

А затем придётся городить такой огород:

```
cols = [x+tuple(y) for x in [tuple(c.split("_")) for c in df_summ.columns.to_list()] for y in df2.columns.to_list() if y not in x]
res = pd.concat([df_summ[f"{c[0]}_{c[1]}"].add(df2[c[2]]) for c in cols], axis=1, keys=cols)
res.columns = [f"{x[0]}_{x[1]}+{x[2]}" for x in res.columns.values]
```

Ну и res, соответственно:

```
   A_B+D  A_B+E  A_C+B  A_C+D  A_C+E  A_D+B  A_D+E  A_E+B  A_E+D  A_F+B  ...  \
0    992    143    555    996    147    559    151    563   1004    567  ...   
1    112    157    679    116    161    683    165    687    124    691  ...   
2    123    175    757    127    179    761    183    765    135    769  ...   
3    136    188    872    140    192    876    196    880    148    884  ...   

   K_M+D  K_M+E  K_P+A  K_P+B  K_P+D  K_P+E  M_P+A  M_P+B  M_P+D  M_P+E  
0   1064    215    336    627   1068    219    340    631   1072    223  
1    184    229    307    751    188    233    311    755    192    237  
2    195    247    421    829    199    251    425    833    203    255  
3    208    260    310    944    212    264    314    948    216    268
```

Comment: а получиться это сделать по порядку? с начала получаем `df_summ`, и работаем уже с  `df_summ` суммируем его с `df2` и на выходе тот же результат надо получить. `res`

Comment: @VEL - дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам @strawdog  !